# Linear SDE and changes of measure

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I have just started reading about stochastic calculus, and I am confused about transforming certain types of SDE using the Girsanov theorem. Here is an example from the book *"Elementary stochastic calculus with finance in view"* by T.Mikosch p.180-182:

Suppose that we have an underlying probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and $(W_{t})_{t\ge 0}$ be a Brownian motion wrt $\mathbb{P}$. Consider the linear SDE

$$dX_{t}=cX_{t}dt+\sigma X_{t}dW_{t}$$

where $c$ and $\sigma$ are constants. The rigorous meaning of the above is that $(X_{t})_{t}$ is a stochastic process such that

$$X_{t}=X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t} cX_{t}dt+\int_{0}^{t} \sigma X_{t}dW_{t}$$

The last term refers to the Ito integral, into which the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ participates directly in the definition.

Consider the process $\widetilde{X}_{t}=e^{-rt}X_t$, where $r$ is a constant. By Ito lemma

$$d\widetilde{X}_{t}=\widetilde{X}_{t}[(c-r)dt+\sigma dW_{t}]$$

Now consider the substitution $\widetilde{W_{t}}=\dfrac{c-r}{\sigma}t+W_{t}$, hence $d\widetilde{W_{t}}=\dfrac{c-r}{\sigma}dt+dW_{t}$ and thus

$$d\widetilde{X}_{t}=\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{t}} \ \ \ (*)$$

So far, so good. Everything is still under the measure $\mathbb{P}$. Using the Girsanov theorem, there exists a probability measure $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$, equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$, with respect to which $\widetilde{W}_{t}$ is a martingale.

It is then claimed that $\widetilde{X}_{t}$ is a martingale wrt $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$, since the Ito integral $\int_{0}^{t}\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{t}}$ is a martingale wrt to $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$. However, this seems to mean that the equality $(*)$ is interpreted as saying that

$$
\widetilde{X}_{t}=\widetilde{X}_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{t}}
$$
where the Ito integral $\int_{0}^{t}\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{t}}$ was computed using $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$. To me, however, such an equality so far is only justified if we used the measure $\mathbb{P}$, as it was the only measure used to reach $(*)$.

So, my question is the following:

> Do we get the same random variable when we compute an Ito integral such as $\int_{0}^{t}\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{t}}$,  using two different, but equivalent probability measures like $\mathbb{P}$ and $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ ?

The definition of Ito integral uses the underlying probability measure from what I know, and convergence in $L^2(\widetilde{\mathbb{P}})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ is not the same as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606084/relation-between-l2-mu-convergence-and-l2-nu-convergence) post shows.

The post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285742/is-the-stochastic-integral-invariant-under-equivalent-change-of-probability) seems to say the answer for my question is yes, but I would like for someone to confirm this.

In case I am terribly confusing something, comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$d\widetilde{X}_{t}=\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{t}} \ \ \ (*)$$

still holds under the new measure $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$. This measure is defined to be equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$ so that the measures agree on events that have measure zero (and one). This implies that all mechanical relationships (equalities that hold for sure) between different stochastic processes under $\mathbb{P}$ must also hold under $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$. Conditional on the realization for $\widetilde{W}$ say $\omega\in \Omega$ you hence get the same value for $\int_{0}^{t}\sigma \widetilde{X}_{t}d\widetilde{W_{s}}$ under both measures.

Comment: Can you explain your last sentence? Why are the Ito integrals the same under both measures?

Comment: @user223794 That is more formally explained here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285742/is-the-stochastic-integral-invariant-under-equivalent-change-of-probability